# why iam unable to concatenate the string here?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int i = 4;
    d = 4.0;
    string s = "HackerRank";

    int a;
    double b;
    string c;                          
    
    cin >> a; 
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;


    a = a + i;
    b = b + d;


    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << "" + s + c;

    return 0;
}

// Declare second integer, double, and String variables.

// Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
// Note: If you have trouble reading the entire string, please go back and review the Tutorial closely.

// Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.

// Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.

// Concatenate and print the String variables on ne
// The 's' variable above should be printed first.
```

Comment: What happened? Did you get an error message?

Comment: What happens after you fix the compilation errors?

Comment: You need a type here, probably double: `d = 4.0;` You need to include the string header, and you need to use `std::string`, `std::cin`, `std::cout`, and `std::endl`.

Comment: There is no text in your question. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You have missed adding including string. Also declaration for d variable was not correct. Could you please try with below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include<string>


int main()
{
  int i = 4;
  double d = 4.0;
  std::string s = "HackerRank";

int a;
double b;
std::string c;                          

std::cin >> a; 
std::cin >> b;
std::cin >> c;


a = a + i;
b = b + d;


std::cout << a << std::endl;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
std::cout << "" + s + c;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend `using namespace std;`. It's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Included string header
The overload for operator<< for std::cout  is only defined in  so you need to add string header.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i = 4;
    float d = 4.0;
    string s = "HackerRank";

    int a;
    double b;
    string c;                          
    
    cin >> a; 
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;


    a = a + i;
    b = b + d;


    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << "" + s + c<<"\n";

    return 0;
```